# Alphabetically ordered list from mysqli join query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to print out an alphabetically ordered list of usernames after using a mysqli join query to select userid's from a friends table.

Friends table consists of

```
id - userid_one - userid_two - friendship_date - friendship_type
```

Users table has a pretty standard layout, and the only field I really need from it is the `username` (to display) and the `userid` to link the two tables

what i want to achieve is the below

**A**
Andy
Anna

B
Bobby
Brian

The code i am using is below.

```
$ir['userid'] //the current users id

$getfriends = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON (friends.userid_one = users.userid OR friends.userid_two = users.userid) WHERE (userid_one = '{$ir['userid']}' OR userid_two = '{$ir['userid']}') ORDER BY username") or die("query error");
        $last="";
        if(mysqli_num_rows($getfriends) == 0)
            {
                print"<li>You have no friends....sorry</li>";
            }
        else
            {

                while($gotf=mysqli_fetch_array($getfriends))
                {
                    if($gotf['userid_one'] == $ir['userid']){$friend = $gotf['userid_two'];}else{$friend = $gotf['userid_one'];}
                    $printed_array = explode(",",$printed);
                    if(!in_array($friend,$printed_array))
                    {
                        $username_of_user = get_username_no_link($friend);
                        $current_letter = $username_of_user[0];
                        if ($last != $current_letter) {
                            print"<li class='Label'>{$current_letter}</li>";
                            $username_of_user = get_username_nd_avatar($friend);
                            print"<li>".$username_of_user."</li>";
                            $last = $current_letter;
                            $printed = $printed.",".$friend;
                        }
                        elseif($last == $current_letter){
                            $username_of_user = get_username_nd_avatar($friend);
                            print"<li>".$username_of_user."</li>";
                            $last = $current_letter;
                            $printed = $printed.",".$friend;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

I have not got much experience of using `JOIN` in mysqli queries and my issue is that I am not getting the list sorted alphabetically as the below example shows.

**A**
Andy

T
Thomas

**S**
Sandra 
Sally

UPDATE-- 
the order in which the usernames display, now seems to change randomly after reloading the page, which is further confusing the matter!

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What's errors are you getting?

Comment: added clearer explanation of my issue

Comment: are you ordering by the correct field, username is what you have Andy seams like a first_name sort of field. also your missing the ending } unless that was just pasted wrong.  - love the error message.

Comment: What are the table definitions?

Comment: updated with table outlines. The names i've given here are jsut examples, so it is definately the username field i'm wanting to use. Corrected the missed } thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question now answered after some playing around. Ended up putting the usernames into an array, then sorting the array alphabetically by value, as well as adding a `$printed_array` array to add each friend to after they were printed to prevent them being printed out twice.

```
$usersnames = array();
                while($gotf=mysqli_fetch_array($getfriends))
                {
                    if($printed != ""){$comma = ",";}
                    if($gotf['userid_one'] == $ir['userid']){$friend = $gotf['userid_two'];}else{$friend = $gotf['userid_one'];}
                    $printed_array = explode(",",$printed);
                    if(!in_array($friend,$printed_array))
                    {
                        $username_of_user = get_username_no_link($friend);
                        $usersnames[] = $username_of_user;
                        $printed = $printed.$comma.$friend;
                    }

                }


                sort($usersnames);
                    foreach($usersnames as $name)
                    {
                        $getuserid = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userid,avatar FROM users WHERE username = '$name' LIMIT 1");
                        $gotuserid = mysqli_fetch_array($getuserid);
                        //var_dump($gotuserid);
                        $displaypic = "<img style='height:30px;vertical-align:middle;margin:5px;' src='".$gotuserid['avatar']."'>";
                            $current_letter = $name[0];
                            if ($last != $current_letter) 
                            {
                                print"<li class='Label'>{$current_letter}</li>";
                                print"<li><a href='profile/".$name."'>".$displaypic.$name."</a></li>";
                                $last = $current_letter;

                            }
                            elseif($last == $current_letter)
                            {
                                print"<li><a href='profile/".$name."'>".$displaypic.$name."</a></li>";
                                $last = $current_letter;
                            }
                    }
```